# Android - Removed artificial Padding on wrapping centered text

Tags: android

I am trying to remove as much space between a ImageView and a TextView with the alignment being centered.
But if the text has some long words that cannot fit in the ongoing lines it breaks to the bottom, but leaving paddings equally on the sides:

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmABh.png)

**Example:**
What is happening:

```
| @@ |   some text here with a    |
| @@ |      looooooong word       |
```

@ = Being the image

I tried to wrap the TextView width and still gives that artificial padding.
I am looking for either of these two solutions:

A way to justify centered text to remove this padding on the sides.

```
| @@ |some   text   here   with  a|
| @@ |    looooooong   word       |
```

Or a way to wrap the TextView width.

```
   | @@ |some text here with a|
   | @@ |   looooooong word   |
```

Comment: Could you add your code?

Comment: Maybe set the width to match constraint? Share your layout code.

Comment: I don't have a specific code for this since we, on our company, use a different framework to program. But the logic is the same.

Comment: I just wanted to know if someone as passed through the same problem as i am facing right now